# How to notify other screen on like button click android

Tags: android, design-patterns, scalability

Let's say I'm working on a social media app like facebook. We can see post on feed page and by clicking the any post that post is visible in a post view screen. If I press like button on the post view screen and go back, I can see in the feed, like has been updated. How to achieve this, let's say my same post is present at various places I want to update respective post everywhere when like is clicked anywhere in that post. I want to implement like button, I'm thinking of observer pattern but I'm little bit confused when it comes to implementation. Can anyone share some reference? How you guys are doing it?

Answer (score 0):

In your specific example what is most likely happening is a `push` from the `database` that contains the new information. You click like which sends an update to the database and you have watchers that poll the database when it changes. The likes are determined by the database not the fact that you clicked the like button, i.e. `single source of truth`.

Look into `RxJava2/3` it is the best library when it comes to Observable pattern.
In terms of `RxJava`

`Flowable` is a type that can constantly get updates. Below is an example of a `DTO` function mixed with a `Room` entity called `Post`.

```
//in DTO
@Query("Select likes from post where post.id = :id")
public Flowable<Integer> getLikes(long id);

//in View (Fragment/Activity)
public void watchLikes(Post post){
      database.postDto.getLikes(post.getId())
          .observeOn(Scheduler.io()) // doesn't block main thread while watching
          .subscribeOn(Schedular.io()) // forces main thread to post changes
          .subscribe(new FlowableSubscriber<Integer>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete() {}
                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable t) {}
                @Override
                public void onNext(Integer likes) {
                     //allows the update of a view from another thread via a post.
                     runOnUIThread(new Runnable(){ 
                          @Override
                          public void run(){
                                  //Update view that contains post with new likes number.
                          }
                     });

                }
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Subscription subscription) {
                      subscription.request(Long.MAX_VALUE); //so it never stops
                }
           }
     );
}
```

I wouldn't use this example in a real use case because there are better options like `Paging` the entire post list to an `Adapter` attached to a `RecyclerView` and updating the entire list with a diff algorithm.